# Run cucumber tests based on tags

Tags: tags, automated-tests, cucumber, logic, cucumber-java

I'm trying to run some cucumber test based on the tags of the testcase.

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = {"<glue value>"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber-json-reports/monitor-cucumber-report.json"},
        tags =
                {
                        "@monitor",
                        "not @_ignore",
                        "not @under_construction"
                }
)
public class MonitorCucumberTests extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {}
```

other file:

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = {"<glue value>"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber-json-reports/monitor-cucumber-report.json"},
        tags =
                {
                        "@monitor",
                        "not @_ignore",
                        "not @under_construction",
                        "not @<none_monitor_feature>"
                }
)
public class MonitorCucumberTests2 extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {}
```

feature file:

```
@monitor @verification @hourly
Feature: Verification flow

  Scenario Outline: Verification happy flow
    Given stuff
    When do stuff


@monitor @verification @hourly @<none_monitor_feature>
Feature: Verification flow with extra

  Scenario Outline: Verification happy flow with extras
    Given stuff
    When do stuff with extra
```

If i run with `MonitorCucumberTests`  it runs both testcases as expected.
If i run with `MonitorCucumberTests2` it still runs both testcases.

I don't get how to run the test caseses with @monitor, but only if it dont have any of the other tags

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did set a variable so i dint run with MonitorCucumberTests2.